# MySQL JOIN in joomla / Virtuemart

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have a sql query that I wish to use in my joomla db but I can't seem to get it to work.

The SQL I have written is fine for phpmyadmin but I don't know the sql for joomla. This i s my sql:

```
SELECT T1.`product_in_stock` FROM `jos_virtuemart_products` AS T1 
INNER JOIN `jos_children` AS T2 ON T1.`virtuemart_product_id` = T2.`xs_id` 
where T2.`xs_id` = 47;
```

I have no idea how to write this in the joomla way and can only find articles on standard select queries.

My Joomla code is:

Thanks,

James

Comment: the query seems correct  .. so what's your problem .. error  ? no result ? wrong result ? .. update you question add   a proper data sample and the expected  result please

Comment: Sorry, to explain further - my issue is how to translate that using the joomla DB syntax. I have so far:   $db = JFactory::getDbo();
// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('xs_id');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__children'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('product_id'). ' = ' . $db->quote($bproduct_id)); For a single query. Is there a way to make a INNER JOIN in this way?